# Why PNPM marks my package with "version: link:" after "pnpm install ..." command?

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, pnpm, renovate

I have a package, which is published in NPM. In this package, I used the same package as its one of dependencies,
https://github.com/tal-rofe/cz-vinyl

So as your can see, the package name is `cz-vinyl`, with latest version of `2.5.0`.
**Most important**, my `package.json` file includes: `"cz-vinyl": "2.5.0"`, so I use the package as a dependency.

In the package, I export some TypeScript types in its `package.json` file:

```json
    "exports": {
        ".": {
            "types": "./dist/config.d.ts",
            "require": "./dist/index.cjs"
        }
    },
```

However, when I have a TypeScript file, https://github.com/tal-rofe/cz-vinyl/blob/main/czvinyl.config.ts, where I do:

```
import type { CzVinylConfig } from 'cz-vinyl';
```

I get an error: `Cannot find module 'cz-vinyl' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)`. I didn't understand why is it the case, because I did export my TypeScript types in the package. Then I found out that PNPM uses this self package as link to the source code.

From `pnpm-lock.yaml` file:

```yaml
  cz-vinyl:
    specifier: 2.5.0
    version: 'link:'
```

And when I look at `./node_modules/cz-vinyl` **Indeed I just see my source code**, instead of the distributed files from NPM. I tested it in completely different repository: I installed `cz-vinyl` in other project, **using PNPM**, and I saw my distributed NPM code. And that I why I get the error I pasted here.

So, why does it even happen? And how can I make PNPM to use the NPM distributed code instead of linking directly to the source code?

---

After more investigation, I found out that issue occurs after Renovate makes a pull request on my code to update some dependencies' versions.

After another investigation I traced the Renovate logs, and found out what the process is:

1. Renovate modifies my `package.json` file with this change:
   [image]
2. Renovate runs: `pnpm install --recursive --lockfile-only --ignore-scripts --ignore-pnpmfile`
3. Renovate updates my `pnpm-lock.yaml` with the new changes according to step 2.

I could replicate this issue locally:

1. Run `git clone https://github.com/tal-rofe/cz-vinyl.git`
2. Modified manually my `package.json` file as the same way Renovate did
3. Run locally `pnpm install --recursive --lockfile-only --ignore-scripts --ignore-pnpmfile`
4. I can see my `pnpm-lock.yaml`changes:
   [image]